# CSS Table Rows and Cells Width

Tags: css, css-tables

Here I have very tricky issue. )
How to make 3rd cell with Width 100% and make bottom row standalone from the first row?

```css
/* Table */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .40);
}

/* Grid */

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

/* Grid Width */

.cell-1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.cell-2 {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Decoration */

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.cell {
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell cell-1">1</div>
      <div class="cell cell-1">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell cell-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I rewrite your program using Table Tag. The Program is written below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .40);
}

/* Grid */

tr {
  display: table-row;
}

td {
  display: table-cell;
}

/* Decoration */

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
}

td {
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is how Tables are supposed to be built. Forcing `div`s to act as tables and table-cells is not the right way and makes the code less readable imo.

Comment: But HTML Tables is obsolete. Everything must be styled with CSS. Yes, I need CSS colspan alternative.

Comment: That is not possible, if you have doubt you can check in other site.